# How to correct the image according to the camera's matrix with the distortion coefficients?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm not sure the the unit of the camera's matrix(mm, etc.):

```
camera matrix ={0.0074209246, 0.0, 0.026450, 0.0, 0.0074209246, -0.0560390.0, 0.0, 1.0}
matrix distortion= {-4.179306e-005,-4.179306e-005,,2.008752e-005,-2.959854e-005}
```

Comment: there is a function called undistort() or something very similar

Answer (score 0):

```
undistort(image, imageUndistorted, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs);
```

Where `image` is the captured image, `imageUndistorted` is a `mat` to store the undistorted image. The units are pixels.